# Push values in array and display results in message box using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have multiple items in a website. I m getting in hand quantity of each selected items using jquery .each() function. Performing some validation and using if condition to check and display alert message.

Here is my code

```
var result = [];
    jQuery('#ct1').on("click", function(event){
    jQuery(':checkbox:checked').each(function (i) {
    var qtyval = jQuery(this).parent().parent().siblings('.item-cell-      detail').find('.qtyonhand').text(); 
    var qty= parseFloat(qtyval);
    console.log(qty); // its showing valid result
    var strrsult = result.push(qty); //Here im not getting desired value
    alert(strrsult); // want to display all the values in a single alert box
    });
    });
```

How to display all values in a single alert box. As i'm new to jquery so please help.

Comment: This would create an alert box everytime you push something to the array. But you have to do the alert after the loop. 
var strrsult = result.toString(); alert(strrsult);

Comment: Tried your solution but i'm getting two alert boxes one is showing value1 value and the next one is value1,value2

Comment: post loop im trying to show alert but getting error that strrsult is not defined

Comment: You have to use my lines both after the loop. The result seems like you are still in the loop. There should only be 1 alert box

Comment: Also the var strrsult = result.toString() should be after the loop

Comment: Thanks its working now

Comment: If you want different formats you can also google array.join() method

Comment: If i want to add a if condition inside loop and based on this condition want to show an alert box then how can i modify this code because in this code i have to display alert box outside the loop

Comment: Like this code                                                                                        var result = [];
jQuery('#ct1').on("click", function(event){
jQuery(':checkbox:checked').each(function (i) {        
qtyval = jQuery(this).parent().parent().siblings('.item-cell-detail').find('input[name="qty"]').val();                                             
var qtyval1 = jQuery(this).parent().parent().siblings('.item-cell-detail').find('.qtyonhand').text(); 
var strrsult = result.push(qtyval1);
if(qtyval > qtyval1){
var strrsult = result.toString(); alert(strrsult);
} });});

Comment: Thanks....but its showing two alert boxes because alert is in inside loop how to get values in single box in this case?

Comment: If you want that it only alerts the first time the if condition passes, you can create a boolean flag before the loop like
var hasAlerted = false;
add && !hasAlerted to the if condition and set hasAlerted to true in the if block

Answer (score 0):

```
alert(JSON.stringify(strrsult))
```

will alert the values in your array and if you want to display one per line then

```
alert(strrsult.join("\n"));
```

Comment: When using .push to add values in array the result which i'm getting is different.in qty variable im getting 0,103 values but in strrsult im getting 1,1 values

Comment: you are confusing me now. Are you saying that console.log values are diffferent to what you alert?

Comment: yes after pushing in array getting different result